# Error when using RSpec's `all` matcher with Capybara's `have_css` matcher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm just getting started with feature specs using RSpec (and Capybara). I'm testing my ActiveAdmin dashboard and I want to check that all panels have an orders table as shown in this snippet:

```
feature 'admin dashboard', type: :feature do
  def panels
    page.all('.column .panel')
  end

  describe 'all panels' do
    it 'have an orders table' do
      expect(panels).to all(have_css('table.orders tbody'))
    end
  end
end
```

I've used the `all` matcher a lot in my unit tests but it doesn't appear to work when wrapping Capybara's `have_css` matcher because I'm getting the following error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(panels).to all(have_css('table.orders tbody'))
TypeError:
  no implicit conversion of Capybara::RackTest::CSSHandlers into String
```

Am I correct in my assumption that RSpec's built-in `all` matcher should work with other matchers as well?

Note: I'm using `describe` and `it` instead of `feature` and `scenario` in this instance because I'm testing output rather than user interaction scenarios (see my [other question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/256557/should-i-be-writing-feature-or-request-specs)).

Comment: Unfortunately there is a conflict between RSpec's `all` and Capybara's `all` see [Capybara Issue 1396](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1396). The `all` that you are calling is actually Capybara's `all`.

Comment: D'oh, you're right @JustinKo. Do you have a workaround to suggest?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately there is a conflict between RSpec's `all` and Capybara's `all` see [Capybara Issue 1396](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1396). The `all` that you are calling is actually Capybara's `all`.

**Solution 1 - Call BuiltIn::All Directly**

The quickest solution would be to call RSpec's `all` method directly (or at least that code that it executes.

The expectation will work if you use `RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::All.new` instead of `all`:

```
expect(panels).to RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::All.new(have_css('table.orders tbody'))
```

**Solution 2 - Redefine all**

Calling the BuiltIn:All directly does not read nicely so might get annoying if used often. An alternative would be to re-define the `all` method to be RSpec's `all` method. To do this, add the module and configuration:

```
module FixAll
  def all(expected)
    RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::All.new(expected)
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include FixAll
end
```

With the change, the `all` in the following line will behave like RSpec's `all` method.

```
expect(panels).to all(have_css('table.orders tbody'))
```

Note that if you want to use Capybara's `all` method, you would now always need to call it using the session (ie `page`):

```
# This will work because "page.all" is used
expect(page.all('table').length).to eq(2)

# This will throw an exception since "all" is used
expect(all('table').length).to eq(2)
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using solution 2. By the way, where's the "standard" place to put helper modules like this? I've gone for spec/support/helpers/fix_all_helper.rb.

Comment: Some where in the "support" folder seems to make sense. Beyond that, given the non-standardness of this approach, there is probably no standard.

Comment: I tried this in a Cucumber environment (putting the file in `features/support/fix_rspec_all.rb`) and I got an error about `RSpec.configure` not existing.  So instead, I removed that configure block, and just called `World(FixAll)` which added my method to the Cucumber "World".  I actually called my matcher `each` so that they wouldn't be conflicting, and I could use both.  See alternate answer below

Answer (score 0):

I used a very similar approach to the accepted answer, but in a Cucumber environment I was getting errors about `RSpec.configure` not existing.  Also, I wanted to call the matcher something besides `all` so that I could use them both without conflicts.  This is what I ended up with

```
# features/support/rspec_each.rb

module RSpecEach
  def each(expected)
    RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::All.new(expected)
  end
end

World(RSpecEach) # extends the Cucumber World environment
```

Now I can do things like:

```
expect(page.all('#employees_by_dept td.counts')).to each(have_text('1'))
```